# Can we merge this both tag [android-n] and [android-7.0-nougat]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Both the tags [android-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-n)  and [android-7.0-nougat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-7.0-nougat) used for [**`Android 7.0 Nougat(API level 24)`**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0)

[android-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-n)

- Android N (aka Nougat, Android 7, API24)

[android-7.0-nougat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-7.0-nougat)

- Android 7.0 Nougat (API level 24), formerly known as "Android N".

I propose merging the tags [android-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-n) and [android-7.0-nougat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-7.0-nougat) , because Both the tags are used for question related to `Android 7.0 Nougat(API level 24)`

Questions tagged [android-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-n) :  193 questions

Questions tagged [android-7.0-nougat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-7.0-nougat) :   697 questions

> **NOTE :** for API level 25(7.1) there is a tag available [android-7.1-nougat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-7.1-nougat)

Comment: Same for [android-o] and [android-8.0-oreo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[android-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-n) > [android-7.0-nougat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-7.0-nougat)

```
updating post history, 223 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 192 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 179 rows affected
destroying 'android-n': [android-n] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for master tag, new count: 876
tag remapping of [android-7.0-nougat] and [android-n] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
21 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
3 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym android-n -> android-7.0-nougat was approved!
```

---

[android-o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-o) > [android-8.0-oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-8.0-oreo)

```
updating post history, 276 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 255 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 239 rows affected
destroying 'android-o': [android-o] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for master tag, new count: 1043
tag remapping of [android-8.0-oreo] and [android-o] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
22 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
6 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym android-o -> android-8.0-oreo was approved!
```